# using django.core JSON serializer with JQuery, syntax inconsistency

Tags: jquery, python, django, json

I'm trying to pass a 'User' object (which is a Django.models.Model) to my web view, however Django and jQuery don't seem to be agreeing on what constitutes valid JSON.

The relevant pieces of code:

The object in question, User (in models.py)

```
class User(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    bank_account = models.CharField(max_length = 9)
    email = models.EmailField()
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField()
    credit = models.IntegerField()
```

The view (in views.py):

```
def user(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.filter(pk=user_id)

    JSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
    json_serializer = JSONSerializer()
    json_serializer.serialize(user)

    data = json_serializer.getvalue()

    if request.is_ajax():
        return render_to_response("pos/user.json", {'user': data});
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400);
```

The Django template (pos/user.json):

```
{{user}}
```

The jQuery code:

```
    var resp = $.getJSON("user/" + $('#elem').text() + ".json",function(json) {
        $('#debug').html("json gotten!");
    });
    resp.error(function(){$('#debug').html(resp.responseText);});
```

The result is that #elem remains unchanged, #debug gets the value:

```
[{"pk": 4, "model": "pos.user", "fields": {"city": "test", "name": "test", "barcode": "test", "credit": 10, "isAdmin": false, "adress": "test", "email": "example@example.com", "bank_account": "000000000"}}]
```

If I remove the square brackets from the output, #debug becomes "json gotten!".

From the information I have so far I'm guessing that the issue may be that the Django serializer outputs something almost, but not quite, entirely unlike JSON. I haven't been able to find the square brackets in any specification of JSON (atleast, not in this position).

The solution many suggest is using the simplejson library, but as my User is a django.models.Model and its fields are of the type django.models.*Field, simplejson gave an error of the "do not want" variety.

Is there any way I can fix this code, without resorting to manually trimming the '[' and ']' from my serialized string?

P.S.: There are some questions on SO that are similar to this one, I have however not been able to find an actual answer

Edit: added the 'User' object, to avoid confusion.

Edit: simply passing one object to the serializer does not work, this gives the error: "'User' object is not iterable"

Comment: JSON from Django is a `[` list of objects `]`.  Perhaps your getJSON isn't prepared for a list of objects.

Comment: That's probably what is going wrong.. I'm wondering what the best solution is to get Django's serializer to convert a single object to JSON (as my response to Eric Fortin below shows: it's not as simple as just passing one object ;) )

Comment: That post has apparently disappeared, I've incorporated the answer into my original question.

Comment: I did removed it since it wasn't helping to answer your question.

Comment: Okay, I'm quite new at this, so I'm not entirely up to snuff with regards to the ways and means of SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you're using render_to_response, and not setting a mimetype. Try just returning `HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')`

Comment: I'm currently not near a pc where I can test this, but shouldn't this also be a problem if I trim the `[` and `]` ? 
I'll try the suggestion tomorrow, as soon as I'm near my laptop again, Thanks!

Comment: The `[` and `]` are a red herring, they are perfectly valid in JSON (as in Javascript). Like in Python, they indicate a list (array) of items.

Comment: Wow, you were absolutely right! This fixed the error. Thanks!